# Cmocka link apache runtime functions

Tags: c, apache, unit-testing, apr, cmocka

I am trying to unit test an Apache module with Cmocka.

When I run the simple tests I get an error that it can't find function `ap_rprintf`. I try to build like this:

```
gcc -o run_test mod_hello.c run_test.c \
  -lcmocka -lapr-1 \
  -I/usr/include/apache2 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0
```

I isolated the issue into a very simple case at https://github.com/tvlooy/cmocka_apache_module/

What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

it compiles by adding the linker flag `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files`